# How to use whereBetween and like operator together in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I need to change the below MySQL code to laravel format using where, between and like operators together:

```
select count(id) from tbl1 
where created_at BETWEEN 
   '2018-12-10%' AND '2018-12-12%'
```

Comment: Why do you want to treat dates as strings? Simple [SARGable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/5070879) expression `created_at >= '2018-12-10' AND created_at < '2018-12-13'` Effective range: *`2018-12-10 00:00:00 - 2018-12-12 23:59:59`*

Comment: please write this query in laravel format. thanks

Comment: I am not a PHP/Laravel programmer.

Comment: `DB::table('test')->whereBetween('created_at',[$sdate.'%', $enddate.'%'])->count();`

Comment: thank you Lukasz Szozda , I got the answer the above query works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer as below:

```
\DB::table('tbl1')->whereBetween('created_at',[$sdate.'%', $enddate.'%'])->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Model you could use the `whereBetween` method, take a look at the following example:
`User::query()->whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])->count();`